# Ruby on Rails foreign key field cannot be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application where there is a `User` model and a `Role` model.

Role can be either Superuser, Admin or User.

My Users table migration looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :password_digest
      t.boolean :banned
      t.references :role, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I go to create my user using HTTP POST, I keep getting the error:

```
Role must exist
```

Which is Rails telling me the field `role` for my User model cannot be null.

So I thought, well, I want my user created through HTTP POST to default to "User" role, so I have this in my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  has_secure_password
  # validates :role, allow_nil: true

  before_validation do
    self.banned = false

    # Users created through HTTP POST request should always
    # default to 'User' role.
    # Rails console created users will be explicitly set
    # to 'Superuser' or 'Admin' roles.
    self.role = Role.find_by({title: 'User'})
    puts "User model set role fired!"
  end
end
```

This fixes the errors but now I have a problem.

When an admin user tries to change an existing user's role from "User" to "Admin", the `before_validation` method always fires, forever overwriting my POST params to specify new role for user.

In effect, I can never change the role of any users.

Am I doing something wrong?

Surely there's a way to create a user without any roles assigned at the start and then set the role later...

I've been scratching my head for hours.

### UPDATE

I found this: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Oh man. I forgot about Rails 5 `belongs_to` has been changed to be required by default now, needed to set `optional: true` for my initial problem :D

My new problem after trying Steve's suggestions is my Rails test is giving me errors:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank
```

Even though I'm doing an update operation not a create user operation. I wonder if Bcrypt is interfering somehow?

Perhaps I only needed the `password_digest` field when I generated my User model using the rails console command?

More investigating needed...

### UPDATE 2

I think I solved it...at least all my tests are now passing, though I'm still skeptical :D

I created a new migration file and removed the Password column from Users table, my tests still passes including creating a new user.

I was able to still create users in my `rails console --sandbox`

A few other mistake I think is my user strong parameters needed the field changed from `:role` to `:role_id`. Although the User model field is named `role`, in the database, the foreign key is actually `role_id` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the assignments conditional on whether there's already a value...

```
  before_validation do
    self.banned = false if banned.nil?
    self.role ||= Role.find_by(title: 'User')
  end
```

Or you can do it only on create....

```
  before_validation do
    if new_record?
      self.banned = false
      self.role = Role.find_by(title: 'User')
    end
  end
```

But frankly the way I normally see initial defaults set is in the `create` method of the controller

```
def create
  @user = User.assign_attributes(user_params)
  @user.banned = false
  @user.role = Role.find_by(title: 'User')
  if @user.save
    # ...
```

Comment: Steve, thanks for these suggestions. I tried them, I got new errors now about `Password can't be blank` when I tried to update a user's username. I am beginning to think maybe my User model create table didn't need the `password` and `password_digest` fields...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `before_action` only on create:

```
before_validation :my_action, on: :create
```